# General solution for vector differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, laplacian, fluid-dynamics

I encounter a vector differential equation in solving poroelastic flow as follows:

$$\nabla\times\nabla\times\boldsymbol{\Phi}=\mathbf{A}+\nabla(\frac{r^2}{2}\chi)$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is an unknown vector and $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector.
$\mathbf{A}$ is a known vector that satisfies the vector Laplace equation and $\chi$ is a known scalar that satisfies the scalar Laplace equation as follows:
$$\nabla^{2}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0}, \quad\quad \nabla^{2}\chi=0.$$
My question is: how to find a general solution of $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ in terms of $\mathbf{A}$, $\chi$, and $\mathbf{r}$.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the general solution to the equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is rather simple, however in order to make the solution unique, one would have to specify further constraints on the field $\mathbf{\Phi}$.

Using the Helmholtz decomposition of the field, we write

$$\mathbf{\Phi}=-\nabla E+\nabla\times\mathbf{B}~~\\ ~\\ ~~\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$$

This allows us to rewrite the equation as

$$\nabla^2(\nabla\times \mathbf{B})=-\left(\mathbf{A}+\nabla\frac{\chi r^2}{2}\right)$$

which shows that the function

$$\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{r})=-\nabla E(\mathbf{r})+\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_V d^3\mathbf{r'}\frac{\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r'})+\frac{1}{2}\nabla\left(\chi(\mathbf{r')} \mathbf{r'}^2\right)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$
is a solution to the problem posed for any scalar function $E(\mathbf{r})$ only if, of course, the source fields obey the additional constraint

$$2\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}+\nabla^2(\chi r^2)=0$$

This constraint can be subsequently eliminated if one writes

$$\mathbf{A}=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla(\chi \mathbf{r}^2)+\nabla\times\mathbf{\Omega}$$

and then the solution can be written concisely in the form

$$\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{r})=-\nabla E(\mathbf{r})+\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla \times\int_V d^3\mathbf{r'}\frac{\mathbf{\Omega}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$

If, additionally, wlog we require that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{\Omega}=0$, then this field satisfies the Airy equation:

$$\nabla^4\mathbf{\Omega}=0$$

Note that the auxiliary field $\mathbf{\Omega}$ introduces no new constraints on $\chi$ since

$$0=-\nabla^2(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A})=\nabla^4(\chi r^2/2)=\left(\frac{\mathbf{r}^2\nabla^2}{2}+4\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla+10\right)\nabla^2\chi$$
which vanishes automatically whenever $\chi$ obeys the Laplace equation.

**EDIT:** In answer to a question in the comments, with $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ divergenceless, it is possible to express it in terms of $\mathbf{A}$, since

$$\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf{\Omega}=-\nabla^2\Omega=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$$
and hence
$$\mathbf{\Omega}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^3\mathbf{r'}\frac{\nabla\times\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it is really helpful! Just a couple of questions: 
1. Is E(r) a scalar or vector?  in the second line, there is a curl of E. 
2. How does E relate to A and \chi? Does E satisfy the Laplace equation? if so, can we say that E=\chi as they both satisfy the scalar  Laplace equation? 
3. Why do we assume \Omega is divergence-free?

Comment: 3) We can assume that because the Helmholtz decomposition in $\mathbb{R}^3$ [allows us to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition). 1) E is a scalar and the equation with the curl of E was an oversight. 2) E is a function that is free to be chosen. It is not determined by the equation you wrote, and you would need more equations to specify it. For example, if you assume that $\Phi$ is divergenceless, then E satisfies the Laplace equation and can be chosen to be zero.

Comment: To convince yourself, plug in the solution to your equation for $\Phi$ and verify it solves it for all $E$.

Comment: got it for the E. one more question: Can we express \boldsymbol{\Omega} in terms of \mathbf{A} ,\chi, and \mathbf{r} explicitly? thank you!

Comment: I wrote something about solving for $\Omega$ in the edit above.